# VBA Cannot Subtract Days From Date

Tags: excel, vba, date, subtraction, dateadd

I’m trying to get the date 4 days older than now. Here is my code

```
Sub calcdate()
Dim nDateTime, oDateTime As Date
nDateTime = Format(Now, "YYMMDD")
oDateTime = Format(DateAdd("d", -4, nDateTime), "YYMMDD")
MsgBox ("Today is " & nDateTime & " And OldDate is " & oDateTime)
End Sub
```

But output is ‘Today is 170604 And OldDate is 02-10-3734”

I Tried to do it without DateAdd

```
nDateTime = Format(Now, "YYMMDD")
oDateTime = nDateTime - 4
```

*Output is ‘Today is 170604 And OldDate is 170604’

I tried these changes

```
nDateTime = Format(Now, "YYMMDD")
oDateTime = DateAdd("d", -4, nDateTime)
```

*Output is ‘Today is 170604 And OldDate is 31-01-2367’

```
nDateTime = Format(Now, "YY-MM-DD")
oDateTime = Format(DateAdd("d", -4, nDateTime), "YY-MM-DD")
```

*Output is ‘Today is 17-06-04 And OldDate is 04-06-2013’

So it seems here it is subtracting years although I put “d”.

last thing i tried:

```
nDateTime = Format(Now, "DD-MM-YY")
oDateTime = Format(DateAdd("d", -4, nDateTime), "DD-MM-YY")
```

*Output is ‘Today is 04-06-17 And OldDate is 31-05-2017’
i want this date, in format 170531, also why did it give me 2017 while i choose format YY only?

Answer (score 1):

Format creates a string so you can no longer sensibly perform calculations on it. Do your formatting afterwards instead:

```
Dim nDateTime As Date, oDateTime As Date
nDateTime = Now
oDateTime = nDateTime - 4
MsgBox "Today is " & Format(nDateTime, "YYMMDD") & " And OldDate is " & Format(oDateTime, "YYMMDD")
```

Also, you need to declare the variable type for each variable so, as I've done.

Comment: this worked, thanks @Absinthe

    `Dim oDateTime As Date
    oDateTime = Now - 4
    MsgBox ("OldDate is " & Format(oDateTime, "YYMMDD"))`

i know it might not be optimum that way, but this is not the original code, I will use this to do something else, so this is sufficent.
about declaration, i believe i can declare them together as in my code, i checked it on msdn, and it works anyway
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx]

Comment: @i.fathy- in VBA every variable declaration requires a type (unless you want it to be Variant). You can't just put `As something` at the end of a list of variables

Answer (score 0):

because Format(Now, "YYMMDD") result  is string

```
Dim myDate As Date
Dim nDatetime As String, oDateTime As String

myDate = Now
nDatetime = Format(myDate, "yymmdd")
oDateTime = Format(DateAdd("d", -4, myDate), "YY-MM-DD")
```